# When do I use references?

Tags: c++, reference

My understanding of references is that they are an alias to an already-existing variable - they cannot be null. They are useful for function calls when modifying the original inputs, as references are considered safer than pointers.

Besides the above, and cases where references are mandatory, are there other reasons/use cases to use references as opposed to **already-existing variables** that the references point to?

Edit: Note that I said **Besides the above**. Meaning I want to know when else references are useful - when not required - outside of calling functions (I already know that). I also specifically want to know when references are preferred over the original variables, **not** over pointers (I already learnt from another question to "use references when you can, pointers when you must" when it comes to choosing between the two).

Comment: Use references in case you want to pass a large size argument to a function or method or in case you want to 'store' it in your object (without making a copy of it). References has same features as pointers (regarding polymorphism or rtti). There is no way to point what is "better" or "worse" - reference or pointer, everything depends on the context you use them.

Comment: ITT: OP asks "where do we use references, other than in function calls" and everyone answers "in function calls"

Comment: Tiny part of an answer:  A reference is often useful as a different type alias for an object `if (x->is_a_foo()) { foo& xf=static_cast<foo&>(*x); xf.memberof_foo(...)...}`

Comment: Another tiny part of an answer:  When a messy selection of a small part of an object would otherwise be repeated in a way either too large or just plain wrong:  `T& r=a[++i].b[--j].m_t; ... r(a)+r(b) ...` assuming the appropriate `T::operator()` we want a non messy way to invoke it twice (and not modify i or j twice).

Answer (score 5):

Lets say you have a large structure, or a `std::vector` or a `std::string` object, and you pass that by value to a function. That means that the object is *copied* which might be quite inefficient for large object (like say a vector of a couple of million entries). Then you can use a reference to a constant object like e.g. `std::vector<SomeType> const& my_object`.

Answer (score 4):

We use Reference because of the following things

1. To modify local variables of the caller function.
2. For passing large sized arguments.
3. To avoid Object Slicing.
4. To achieve Run Time Polymorphism in a function.

For more info, see http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-pass-arguments-by-reference-or-pointer/

Answer (score 0):

Use references where you can instead of pointers. Unless you want to manipulate low level memory you should not be dealing with pointers. Another usage would be keeping the main data on heap using new as a pointer and passing a reference of that pointer. But with new unique_ptr, shared_ptr and weak_ptr combination even that is not needed. The only place where a pointer is needed is when your object can be nullptr because references cannot be NULL. You can safely assume that a reference is a valid object unless someone has twisted the code in a perverse way.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common misconception that references are safer than pointers, yet it is a misconception. It is just as easy to generate null-references and other illegal references. And these can propagate quite far before blowing up your program. Here are some examples:

- Creation of null-references: Just dereference a null-pointer to pass the result to something that expects a reference.

  ```
  class Foo {
      public:
          Foo() : bar(null_ptr) {}
          void setSize(size_t newSize) {
              delete bar;
              bar = new int[newSize];
          }
          doSomething() {
              myVec.push_back(bar[0]);    //This will blow up somewhere in the push_back() implementation, not here!
          }
      private:
          int* bar;
          std::vector<int> myVec;
  };

  void baz() {
      Foo myFoo;
      myFoo.doSomething();
  }
  ```

  The point is that the code above won't blow up at the point where you dereference the null-pointer, it will just silently create a null-reference. That is legal, because dereferencing a null-pointer is defined to be undefined behavior, and creating a null-reference is a valid thing for the compiler to do.

  The null-reference will be successfully passed to `std::vector<>::push_back()`, which will segfault only when it itself tries to use the reference to actually get to the value behind it.
- Dangling references: Just let the referenced object end its lifetime before the reference does. Again, just the same problem as with pointers:

  ```
  std::vector<int> foo;
  foo->push_back(7);
  int& bar = foo[0];                   //perfectly legal
  bar *= 6;                            //perfectly legal
  foo->push_back(8);                   //perfectly legal
  cout << "The answer is: " << bar;    //BOOM, bar is dangling, undefined behavior results
  ```

  Note: This code may actually run as expected, just like code accessing a dangling pointer may reproducably run as expected.
- Out-of-range references: Just as easily done as with pointers:

  ```
  std::vector<int> array;
  array.resize(7);
  int& bar = array[7];    //undefined behavior, even if the compiler detects this, it will silently ignore it
  bar = 42;    //since this is undefined behavior, the compiler may optimize away this line
  ```

  As with the dangling reference, this code may run perfectly fine, but it may not do what you think it does. Due to optimization, it may not even write to the out of range element. Or it may corrupt the heap, or the stack, or both, or silently compute wrong results. Just blowing up with a segfault is actually the most unlikely outcome here.

As you see, the last two example codes don't even require an explicit pointer anywhere, they use only the modern, shiny C++ style data structures. Yet they result in undefined behavior that will not strike at the place where it is invoked. The illegal reference may be propagated any distance from the place where it was created before noticeably bad things start to happen. Which is precisely why people dread using pointers; the danger from pointers and references is the same.

So, really, use references where it makes sense to you. But do not rely on them being "safe".